# issue with testing Linked List's function

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to **test** the following Linked List function:

```
function ListNode(x) {
  this.value = x;
  this.next = null;
}

function removeKFromList(l, k) {
    // create node
    let node = new ListNode();
    // assign node.next to the beginning of the given linked list.
    node.next = l;

    // start iterating through the linked list
    let current = node;
    // while there is still a node
    while(current.next) {
        // if the value of the node equals to given K
        if (current.next.value === k) {
            // remove it from the list by hopping from the one node to the next node
            current.next = current.next.next
        } else {
            // move from one node to the next.
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    //return the linked list
    return node.next;
}
console.log(removeKFromList([3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3));
```

I expect the output to be: `[1, 2, 4, 5]` however, the output is: `[ 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]`

P.S. I would like to note that I am not good at Linked List-related problems, therefore, don't blame me if I am missing some "**obvious**" thing(s).

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger.

Comment: @tgdavies, could you please be more specific, as to what part exactly should I go through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `removeKfromList` function is correct, but it expects its first argument to be a linked list, and it returns a reference to a linked list.

But you call it with an array, and expect the output to be an array.

I guess you got confused by some code challenge sites, which take input from standard input, formatted as an array, but which first convert that input to a linked list, before actually calling the solution code.

In order to make it work outside of that site's framework, you first have to convert the array to a linked list yourself, and then after having called the function, you need to convert the result back to an array or anything printable.

So below I have added two utility functions to do just that -- I didn't touch the code you presented:

```js
function ListNode(x) {
    this.value = x;
    this.next = null
}

function removeKFromList(l, k) {
    // create node
    let node = new ListNode();
    // assign node.next to the beginning of the given linked list.
    node.next = l;

    // start iterating through the linked list
    let current = node;
    // while there is still a node
    while(current.next) {
        // if the value of the node equals to given K
        if (current.next.value === k) {
            // remove it from the list by hopping from the one node to the next node
            current.next = current.next.next
        } else {
            // move from one node to the next.
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    //return the linked list
    return node.next;
}

// All changes are in the part below:

function arrayToList(arr) {
    return arr.reduceRight((next, val) => 
        Object.assign(new ListNode(val), { next })
    , null);
}

function listToArray(list) {
    const arr = [];
    for (let node = list; node; node = node.next) {
        arr.push(node.value);
    }
    return arr;
}

const list = arrayToList([3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
const shorter = removeKFromList(list, 3);
const result = listToArray(shorter);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for your great answer! Really do appreciate your answers!  Yes, you're right, this question is from codesignal(and there are similar questions on sites like leetcode, etc.); for some reason, they did not provide(or require from users) the full code to test their answers!

Answer (score -1):

You probably don't know the meaning of LinkedList. First of all, you created a `node`, and then you have assigned its `next` as `node.next = l`. Here `l` is a list, not a node, you can't call `node.next.next` or `current.next.next`.